# Ansible Azure Creds

Tags: azure, ansible

I am trying to provision infrastructure on Azure Public and Azure Stack. In order to do that I have stored credentials in `$HOME/.azure/credentials` file as advised by [official documentation for Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html). The configuration looks like this:

```
[default]
subscription_id=xxx`enter code here`xxx
client=xxxxx`enter code here`
secret=xxxx`enter code here`x
tenant=xxxxx`enter code here`x

[azurestack]
subscription_id=`enter code here`xxxxxx
client=xxxx`enter code here`x
secret=xxxxx`enter code here`
tenant=xxxxxx`enter code here`
cloud_environemnt=`enter code here`x
```

I tried to execute the playbook as follows:
`sudo ansible-playbook -vvv foo.yml --profile=azurestack`

It does not work for Azure stack. It says the operation called `--profile`. Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the same [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html#storing-in-a-file), they explain how to do it:

> It is possible to store multiple sets of credentials within the credentials file by creating multiple sections. Each section is considered a profile. The modules look for the [default] profile automatically. Define AZURE_PROFILE in the environment or pass a profile parameter to specify a specific profile.

So there is two way, the first one, export first the env variable:

```
sudo AZURE_PROFILE=azurestack ansible-playbook -vvv foo.yml
```

And I have to agree that the second way is not that explicit,… I would try by using `extra-vars`:

```
sudo ansible-playbook -vvv foo.yml --extra-vars "profile=azurestack"
```

But not sure at all that this second is correct, and I'm not able to try it.